Trying to create Subfolders in Excel
Currently if I select multiple cells only the first cell gets subfolders. There are also cells that get selected that do not find the path and therefore cannot create the file. My code is below.
I am attempting to create a folder and hyperlink in excel with 6 subfolders that will always be the same.
Sub FileHyperlink1()
'
'remember to select the cells you want to turn into folders before running the macro

'Default location where to select folder
Dim CreateAt As String
CreateAt = "G:\QUALITY\Corrective Actions\2024"
'Dim OpenAt As String
'OpenAt = "G:\QUALITY\Corrective Actions\2024"

BrowseForFolder = "G:\QUALITY\Corrective Actions\2024"

'get the range of cells that were selected before the macro was run
Dim Rng As Range
Dim maxRows, maxCols, r As Integer
Set Rng = Selection
maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count

'---loop through all cells within selected range---
    r = 1
    Do While r <= maxRows

            'create hyperlink in Excel file to newly created folder
            Dim cnf
            Set cnf = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

                cnf.CreateFolder (BrowseForFolder & "\" & Rng(r))
               ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Rng(r), Address:=BrowseForFolder & "\" & Rng(r)
 'Create subfolder
 
                Dim cnsf
                Set cnsf = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                
                cnsf.CreateFolder (BrowseForFolder & "\" & Rng(r) & "\1_Email")
                cnsf.CreateFolder (BrowseForFolder & "\" & Rng(r) & "\2_Traceability")
                cnsf.CreateFolder (BrowseForFolder & "\" & Rng(r) & "\3_Pictures")
                cnsf.CreateFolder (BrowseForFolder & "\" & Rng(r) & "\4_QA")
                cnsf.CreateFolder (BrowseForFolder & "\" & Rng(r) & "\5_8D")
                cnsf.CreateFolder (BrowseForFolder & "\" & Rng(r) & "\6_Archive")
                        
                'End If

            On Error Resume Next
    
        'if the selected cell contains nothing, then do nothing and go to the next cell
        'End If
       
        r = r + 1
' Macro1 Macro
'
Loop
'
End Sub


Does your selection contain non-contiguous cells?

What happens if you comment-out On Error Resume Next? And what data is in the selected range?

@Blackcat To my knowledge the cells I am selecting are contiguous

@JohnM I Got a path not found error staring at cnsf.CreateFolder (BrowseForFolder & "" & Rng(r) & "\1_Email") For the second selection

The data I'm selecting I want to be the folder name for the folder this macro is creating in G:\Quality\Correctiveactions\2024. And I want the listed subfolder within that newly created folder for each cell I have selected. The cell is currently a callout to a concatenated cell from a different sheet. The selected cell is labeled as =Text(Sheet2!B6, "text")

So put this line immediately before the line that errors and see what appears in your Immediate window: `Debug.Print "'" & BrowseForFolder & "" & Rng(r) & "\1_Email" & "'"

Seems that there is only one cell in the selection. Place this at the beginning of your code. MsgBox Selection.Address What is displayed in the window?

@JohnM Still receiving Path not Found error, which wasn't making sense to me because the macro succesfully creates the parent folder but then fails sub folders. With the command .createfolder

@Blackcat The message box says $B$12:$B$13. That is the range of cells I had selected for this execution

The Debug.Print was never going to fix the problem ... it helps with debugging. What does it show in the Immediate window?

@JohnM My apologies, I'm still learning VBA. Trying to optimize processes at work. In the immediate window Running the code I get 'G:\QUALITY\Corrective Actions\2024\002. E28564100 - Yazaki - Contamination \1_Email'... I just noticed the extra space

I think I found the problem. The cells I was calling had extra spaces in them. Thank you all for the help!

There is a space after 'Contamination'. The call to CreateFolder() ignores the space and creates the folder without it (ie without the trailing space). However, the subsequent string concatenation (ie using the & operator) does not ignore the space and looks for the folder including it. Such a folder does not exist and results in a "Path not found" error.
The simplest solution is to remove the trailing space from the end of the relevant cell (if the cell contains a formula then the space will need to be removed from the cell that is the target of the formula).
The alternative is to enclose all of the instances of Rng(r) in the Trim() function (see Trim) ie Trim(Rng(r)) which will programmatically remove the trailing space.
Having done this, you may need to re-instance your On Error Resume Next statement otherwise you will get "File already exists" errors.

Create Folders From the Selected Cells, Add Hyperlinks, and Create Subfolders

FileSystemObject Object Docs

Sub CreateFoldersHyperlinks()

    ' Remember to select the cells you want to turn into folders
    ' before running the macro this macro.
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Default location where to select folder.
    Const DST_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH As String = _
        "G:\QUALITY\Corrective Actions\2024"
    Dim SUBFOLDER_NAMES() As Variant: SUBFOLDER_NAMES = Array( _
        "1_Email", "2_Traceability", "3_Pictures", _
        "4_QA", "5_8D", "6_Archive")
    
    ' Validate the selection.
    
    If Selection Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range (""" _
            & TypeName(Selection) & """)!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Selection.Parent
    
    ' Create and reference an instance of the 'FileSystemObject' object.
    ' Note that you do this once (no need for other instances).
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Validate the root folder path.
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(DST_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH) Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & DST_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH & """ doesn't exist!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' For each valid value in the cells of the selection,
    ' create a new folder, add a hyperlink to the cell,
    ' and create the specified subfolders.
    
    Dim cell As Range, Value As Variant, Item As Variant
    Dim NewFolderPath As String, SubFolderPath As String
    Dim IsValueNoErrorNoBlank As Boolean, IsPathValid As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        ' Check if the cell value is 'no error no blank'.
        Value = cell.Value
        IsValueNoErrorNoBlank = False
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            If Len(Value) > 0 Then
                IsValueNoErrorNoBlank = True
            End If
        End If
        ' Create the new folder.
        IsPathValid = False
        If IsValueNoErrorNoBlank Then
            NewFolderPath = fso.BuildPath(DST_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH, Value)
            If Not fso.FolderExists(NewFolderPath) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                    fso.CreateFolder NewFolderPath
                On Error GoTo 0
                If fso.FolderExists(NewFolderPath) Then
                    IsPathValid = True
                'Else ' could not create folder
                End If
            Else ' new folder exists
                IsPathValid = True
            End If
        'Else ' value is error or blank
        End If
        ' Create the hyperlink and the subfolders.
        If IsPathValid Then
            ' Create a hyperlink to the new folder path.
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:=NewFolderPath
            ' Create the subfolders.
            For Each Item In SUBFOLDER_NAMES
                SubFolderPath = fso.BuildPath(NewFolderPath, Item)
                If Not fso.FolderExists(SubFolderPath) Then
                    ' Note that the following line could still error out
                    ' due to the limited length of the path!
                    fso.CreateFolder SubFolderPath
                'Else ' subfolder exists
                End If
            Next Item
        'Else ' invalid folder path
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Folders, hyperlinks, and subfolders created.", vbInformation

End Sub

